# Where do you put the value for the datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the datepicker in jQueryUI and need to have the inline datepicker. The documentation says just configure a div with .datepicker rather than an input tag.

However, I can't find out how to assign a date for the picker to display by default. You can have a "value" for the input but what do you do with a div???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation of the `defaultDate` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) says:

> Specify either an actual date via a
>   Date object or as a string in the
>   current dateFormat, or a number of
>   days from today (e.g. +7) or a string
>   of values and periods ('y' for years,
>   'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for
>   days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null for
>   today.

So, you want to make sure the `data.resFullDate` is the same as `dateFormat`, e.g.

```
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: data.resFullDate, // e.g. 10-03-28
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `defaultDate` option to specify the date.

```
<script>
$(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: +7 // next week
        });
});
</script>

Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: I am getting the date from JSON as data.resFullDate. I have tried the following with no success:<code>$('#erStart').timepicker({ defaultDate: data.resFullDate });</code>

Comment: @jgr - timepicker or datepicker?

Comment: @jgr -- working sample using an object with a date in an object at http://jsfiddle.net/vbHqQ/